# In neo4j, a query to count the number of distinct structures

Tags: neo4j

In neo4j my database consists of chains of nodes. For each distinct stucture/layout (does graph theory has a better word?), I want to count the number of chains. For example, the database consists of 9 nodes and 5 relationships as this:

```
(:a)->(:b)
(:b)->(:a)
(:a)->(:b)
(:a)->(:b)->(:b)
```

where (:a) is a node with label a. Properties on nodes and relationships are irrelevant.

The result of the counting should be:

```
------------------------
| Structure        | n |
------------------------
| (:a)->(:b)       | 2 |
| (:b)->(:a)       | 1 |
| (:a)->(:b)->(:b) | 1 |
------------------------
```

Is there a query that can achieve this?

**Appendix**

Query to create test data:

```
create (:a)-[:r]->(:b), (:b)-[:r]->(:a), (:a)-[:r]->(:b), (:a)-[:r]->(:b)-[:r]->(:b)
```

Comment: Are there only supposed to be two nodes in the graph `a` and `b`, with multiple relationships among them, or are these meant to be separate nodes, with multiple labeled as `:a` and multiple labeled as `:b`, meaning there are 4 `:a` nodes in your example and 5 `:b` nodes. Are there supposed to be properties on these nodes? Names, for example?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I updated the question to answer your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Thanks for the clarification.

We can get the equivalent of what you want, a capture of the path pattern using the labels present:

```
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
RETURN [node in nodes(path) | labels(node)[0]] as structure, count(path) as n
```

This will give you a list of the labels of the nodes (the first label present for each...remember that nodes can be multi-labeled, which may throw off your results).

As for getting it into that exact format in your example, that's a different thing. We could do this with [some text functions in APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/misc/text-functions/#text-functions-split-join), specifically `apoc.text.join()`.

We would need to first add formatting around the extraction of the first label to add the prefixed `:` as well as the parenthesis. Then we could use `apoc.text.join()` to get a string where the nodes are joined by your desired '->' symbol:

```
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-->(start) and NOT (end)-->()
WITH [node in nodes(path) | labels(node)[0]] as structure, count(path) as n
RETURN apoc.text.join([label in structure | '(:' + label + ')'], '->') as structure, n
```